# Need a div only to display once every session

Tags: javascript, html, web, splash-screen

I am trying to figure out how to make a certain div to show up once each time a person goes on my website. I have seen two ways of doing this using javascript and php but no success.

Here is my code, I would like (if possible) the #spinner div (and everything in it) to be displayed once every session.

```
<body>
****This part would only be displayed once****
<div id="spinner" style="display: none;">
<div class="sketch">
<canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="224"></canvas>
<script>var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  , context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  , img = new Image()
  , w
  , h
  , offset
  , glitchInterval;

img.src = 'http://www.bccustommade.com/images/loading.png';
img.onload = function() {
  init();
window.onresize = init;
};

var init = function() {
clearInterval(glitchInterval);
canvas.width = w = window.innerWidth;
offset = w * .1;
canvas.height = h = ~~(175 * ((w - (offset * 2)) / img.width));
glitchInterval = setInterval(function() {
    clear();
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 110, img.width, 175, offset, 0, w - (offset * 2), h);
    setTimeout(glitchImg, randInt(250, 1000));
}, 500);
};

var clear = function() {
context.rect(0, 0, w, h);
context.fill();
};

var glitchImg = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < randInt(1, 13); i++) {
    var x = Math.random() * w;
    var y = Math.random() * h;
    var spliceWidth = w - x;
    var spliceHeight = randInt(5, h / 3);
    context.drawImage(canvas, 0, y, spliceWidth, spliceHeight, x, y, spliceWidth, spliceHeight);
    context.drawImage(canvas, spliceWidth, y, x, spliceHeight, 0, y, x, spliceHeight);
}
};

var randInt = function(a, b) {
return ~~(Math.random() * (b - a) + a);
};</script>
</div>
<div class="loading">
    <div class="loading-dot"></div>
    <div class="loading-dot"></div>
    <div class="loading-dot"></div>
<div class="loading-dot"></div>
</div>
</div>
****This part would only be displayed once****
```

Comment: Can you shorten that wall of code to the relevant things and what you have tried?

Comment: I will give me a second and i have tried some php tutorials but none work

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: Yes that looks good but I was heading more towards using a cookie, thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call this php script via javascript or read the PHP vars in javascript directly, but I recommend some kind of backend call.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['spinner']) {
    // Render content
}

// Continue with page or other sutff
?>
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Write these contents until some session has value true. And set session value to true once shown.

I am not familiar with PHP syntax, but  page logic would go like this.

```
if(session contains key "first_time" && session["first_time"] == false){

 print "your code here";
 // set session value to true
 session["first_time"] = true;

}
```

If you want this to be shown on all the pages, include this page in every PHP page